# Are there any Mathematica programs on or about the LMFDB Archive?

Tags: special-functions, number-theory

I would like to explore the [LMFDB Archive](http://www.lmfdb.org/) with L-functions using *Mathematica*.  Is there any *Mathematica* sample code available to get me started?

Comment: Numberphile by any chance?

Comment: It would be very challenging to write code for evaluating $L$-functions more complicated than the built-in ones (`DirichletL[]`, `Zeta[]`, `RamanujanTauL[]`).

Comment: J.M.  Thanks for the suggestion.  It is turning out to be more trouble than its worth. Don